# BFX field to large for a data item increase -S

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am getting the above error when trying to run a script produce to a report. It is a pre-existing script that has been run, successfully many times before. Research has told me that that it is something to do with the stack size? I’m running 10.2B02 in WRQ Reflections. Can anyone tell me what this statement means and how I look up the value of my –S.
Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Paste the error message in the question.

Comment: P-2580 14/10/2013 11:29 BEGIN 10201389481635 - IDLE PLANT () TO EMAILCSV FOR *******
bfx: Field too large for a data item. Try to increase -s. (42)

Comment: FYI -- upper case "S" and lower case "s" are very different parameters.  This message goes with the lower case variety.

Answer (score 0):

-s is a client startup parameter.  You mention "Reflections" so you are probably using a character terminal session.  The -s parameter is on the command line used to start Progress (which might be inside a script).  If there is a -pf somefile.pf on the command line then it is inside that "parameter file".  If it is not specified the default value is 40.  The maximum value is limited by available memory but setting it in the hundreds or even in the thousands is not unheard of.

You can also get the startup values by sending a SIGUSR1 to the _progres process that the session is running.  I.e. kill -USR1  That will (safely) create a "protrace." file that includes startup parameters and a 4gl stack trace.  The file will appear in either the current directory, the home directory or the temp-file directory (I forget which, just look for protrace*).

This error usually means that your code is manipulating a field that is too large. (Like the error says.)  That might be for a lot of reasons.

One common possibility is string concatenation in a loop.

Or you might be calling lots of sub-procedures and passing parameters around.

If "nothing has changed" in the code then it probably just means that some data structure has grown slightly larger over time and increasing -s is really no big deal so long as it solves the problem.

If you keep having to increase it then it is more likely that you have some sort of coding issue.  Maybe you're passing things by value that ought to be passed by reference or maybe you have run away recursion.  Or something else.  You'd need to provide a lot more detail to say for sure.

It is also possible (but unlikely) that you have a corrupt data record that appears to have a field in it that is too large.  You could run "proutil dbName -C dbanalys" as an initial step to see if that is true.

Part of the error message is non-standard -- I'm not certain which log file it is coming from or how it got there (applications can write their own messages) but it seems that it might have something to do with trying to send an e-mail.  So I'd be suspicious that either the list of recipients got too long or that the body of the e-mail is too large.